# bash script runs but does not display values

Tags: bash

my script runs without any errors but does not display the variable values. The output of the screen is two spaced blank lines.

```
#! /bin/bash

set v1=25
set v2 [format "%c" $v1]

echo "$v1"
echo "$v2"
```

Answer (score 2):

`set` isn't used to set the value of a regular variable; it is used to set the positional parameters.

```
$ set v1=25
$ echo "$1"
v1=25
$ v1=25
$ echo "$v1"
25
```

Based on `[format "%c" $v1]`, you appear to be writing a hybrid of Tcl and shell.`A`bash` equivalent would be

```
v2=$(printf "\x$(printf '%x' "$v1"))
```

Comment: Hi chepner, thanks for the input, would it be possible to show a working example of the format command?

Comment: `bash` doesn't really have a simple equivalent to convert an integer into the ASCII character it represents. You may be better off figuring out if you really need to do this.